# In Android, is AbstractWindowedCursor.isBlob() guaranteed to be correct?

Tags: android, sqlite

I see that `AbstractWindowedCursor` has methods to check the type of a column.  This is a great convenience!  But when I look at the `CursorWindow` class, I see that the documentation for `isBlob()` says:

> Checks if a field contains either a blob or is null.

So, does this mean that if I run this check on, say, a String column that contains a NULL value, will it return `true`?  If so, this means I can't rely on that method as a guaranteed type check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Checks if a field contains either a blob or is null.
>
> So, does this mean that if I run this check on, say, a String column that contains a NULL value, will it return true?

I haven't tried it myself but I suspect the answer is 'yes' (either that or there's a typo in the docs).

However, if you run isNull() first and that returns 'true' then you know that it isn't going to be possible to tell what the 'column' type is anyway (the isXxxx methods check the type of data the 'field' contains not the 'column' type).

But if you run isNull() first and it returns 'false' then run isBlob(), if it returns true the field contains a blob.

Comment: Today I learned that SQLite is [dynamically typed](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), meaning that each field can have its own type and is not necessarily the type of the column.  In light of this, I'm betting you're right.  Accepting this as the answer.

Comment: @Neil Traft: Yes, the SQLite designers took a different approach to the rest of the world when they created it. Unconventional but it works. Thanks for the accept.