# Get the affinity of a SQLite column on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

The SQLite C library has a method, `sqlite3_column_decltype()`.  But I cannot find any place where the Android SQLite API makes this method available.  Is there any way to get the declared type of a column without running any SQL (i.e. can I avoid using `PRAGMA table_info`)?

I could have used `AbstractWindowedCursor.isBlob()`, but it says that it will also return true if the field is NULL.  I need something that will guarantee me a value equal to the column's declared type.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing recently. The closest I've found is that the [CursorWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html) class has methods named `isString`, `isLong`, etc. But it's not clear whether this is based on affinity; the interface to these methods requires row as well as column info.

Comment: That appears to give you the type of the value rather than the type of the column.

Comment: Yes, I also assumed that to be the type of the value.  See my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676056/in-android-is-abstractwindowedcursor-isblob-guaranteed-to-be-correct).

Comment: @Neil: I saw your other question after I posted my answer. (I also somehow missed your reference to `AbstractWindowedCursor.isBlob`; sorry about that.) For what it's worth, I went with the SQLite flow and am using Strings for every column at the SQLite level, even if the datatype is Double, Long, etc. But I'm not using blobs, and I can see how that would complicate matters.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine for most use cases that would be fine.  For me it's a problem b/c I generate UI controls based on this data, and I can't know what the data will be ahead of time.  So even if the data is NULL, I still need to know whether I should be creating an empty TextView or an empty ImageView.